# using a usb fingerprint scanner with monodroid

Tags: usb, xamarin.android

I'd like to use monodroid to build an app that reads fingerprints from a USB device.  Is there an SDK out there that I can use to do this?

If I used an existing fingerprint java SDK like http://www.neurotechnology.com/ , can it be mixed into a monodroid project?  If I use the usb api in monodroid, will I be able to somehow use an existing driver to an external usb fingerprint device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt that there is an SDK written for Mono for Android for fingerprint biometrics. However you can mix Java with C#, so you are not out of luck.

So what you essentially can do is write a bunch of classes using the Fingerprint SDK you link to and compile and package it in a jar. If you are smart you also write a couple of helper classes in Java which does the heavy lifting, and the only thing you have to do is to bind it so that it can be invoked from Mono for Android.

More information on how to bind jars can be found in the [Mono for Android documentation.](http://docs.xamarin.com/Android/Guides/Advanced_Topics/Java_Integration_Overview/Binding_a_Java_Library_%28.jar%29)